# How do I set Oracle JDBC to use external authentication using Spring-JPA?

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

I currently have a simple Node app that communicates to an Oracle DB and authenticates using Kerberos. The working code looks like this...

```
oracledb.externalAuth = true;
oracledb.autoCommit = true;
...
get poolConnection(){
    return oracledb.createPool({
        connectString: this.connectionString
    });
}
```

Notice I don't need username and password. I tried to do this same thing in Scala using Spring-JPA. My configuration looks like this...

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myjdbcurl
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect=org:
          hibernate:
            dialect:
              Oracle10gDialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

and a POM like this...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to run I get...

> ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

How do I handle Kerberos Auth with Oracle and Spring-JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case to get it to work my application.yml looked like this...

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...
    validationQuery: select 1 from dual
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        naming:
          implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
jdbc:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...
  driver:
    class:
      name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDrive
```

and I had to add this to my static main that sets the Spring app...

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    System.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES, "KERBEROS5")
    System.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_AUTHENTICATION_KRB5_MUTUAL, "true")
    System.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_AUTHENTICATION_KRB5_CC_NAME, System.getenv("KRB5CCNAME"))
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", System.getenv("KRB5_CONFIG"))
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args :_ *)
  }
```

I tried adding this to the properties after looking through the code but only the above would work.

```
#java:
#  security:
#    krb5:
#      conf: ${KRB5_CONFIG}
#oracle:
#  net:
#    authentication_services: "KERBEROS5"
#    kerberos5_mutual_authentication: "true"
#    kerberos5_cc_name: ${KRB5_CONFIG}
```